# Youtube api returns always testStarting status after submitting transition testing endpoint

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on youtube live streaming for my website. 
The concept is simple, I have a stream and I want to go live, for this I'm doing the following:

- creating broadcast
- creating livestream
- binding livestream and broadcast
- getting rtmp url
- pushing from my media server to youtube given rtmp url

when I'm going to youtube it shows me that the stream status is good: The health is good

- then I'm submitting  transition change to testing, and when I get broadcast lifecycleStatus it always returns testStarting and from this point I can't run live transition.

Code samples:

```
$broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status', $broadcastInsert, []);

$streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn', $streamInsert, []);

$bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind(
                $broadcastsResponse['id'],
                'id,contentDetails',
                ['streamId' => $streamsResponse['id']]
            );


$transitionBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->transition('testing', $broadcastsResponse['id'], 'id,status,contentDetails');
```

**So my question is if anyone has experienced the same issue and how have you solved it, or if I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.**

In addition: when I try to start streaming from youtube interface, even though the stream status is good when I press preview button the start streaming button is always fade and I can't click on it. So maybe this is the youtube issue?

Comment: Live Streaming API's [Troubleshooting and error handling](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started#Error_Handling) states that "If a broadcast becomes stuck with a testStarting or liveStarting status, you need to call the liveBroadcasts.delete method and delete the broadcast. Then create a new broadcast, bind it to your live stream, and continue with the testing process."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's not about just one broadcast or stream that I'm creating, I've created multiple broadcasts and streams (until it reached daily limit 9, and I can't create any more) but it always shows me testStarting status...